# Install asp.net3

Tags: asp.net

When I install ASP.NET 3 I get the following error: "use the role management tool". I enabled .NET 3.0 through the role management tool, and am still getting the error so am not able to proceed with the install. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Please use clearer writing next time and proper punctuation. Are you trying to enable ASP.NET in IIS?
If so, try

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

in %WINDIR%\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727

Comment: I am trying to upgrade asp.net2.0 to asp.net 3

Comment: there is even ASP.NET 4.0 ! :P

Comment: wen I install I am getting the following popup
use role mgmt tool to install
any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

From the question I see that you don't know the environment, so I care to explain:

**ASP.NET is a Microsoft technology to build Web Pages**

.NET is the **Microsoft Framework**

there are **2 versions of ASP.NET**, the Classic (normally called just **ASP.NET**) and the Model View Controler called **ASP.NET MVC**

.NET has more versions, since 1.0 to the brand new 4.0

As I understand, you installed the .NET Framework 3.0 (by the way, install the 3.5 SP1 and you have all you need to create not only 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5 applications)

all you need to do is verify if your application on IIS is pointed to .NET 2.0 and not 1.0 and you should have all it takes to run it.

---

**added**

if order to understand all of this you should have a read at Scott Hanselman Blog

> [How to set an IIS Application or AppPool to use ASP.NET 3.5 rather than 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx)

Comment: how do I verify if my application on IIS is pointed to .net 3 SP2